# Equations for Torque Capacity and Bolt Clamping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, torque

I am doing research into how I can best approximate the torque capacity of several components bolted together in an assembly and specifically when a pattern of bolts is holding several parts together at the same time.

Currently I am thinking of using the following approach that describes the total capacity of clutch because most of the components in question are cylindrical by design.

Quickly going through the setup, a  clutch disc of inner radius r<sub>1</sub> and outer radius r<sub>2</sub> will have a surface area of $$A = \pi(r_2^2-r_1^2)$$
A force F<sub>a</sub> will be applied axially to this clutch and generate a pressure $$p = \frac{F_a}{A} = \frac{F_a}{\pi(r_2^2-r_1^2)}$$

We can describe the differential area as $$dA = rdrd\theta$$

Simarly the differential normal force can be shown as $dN = pdA$, the differential frictional force as $dF = \mu dN$ and the differential torque as $dT = rdF$ respectively.

Substituting all of the above and solving for $dT$ we get $$dT = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{r_1}^{r_2} \frac{\mu F_a}{\pi(r_2^2-r_1^2)} r^2drd\theta$$

Integrating we get a clutch's torque capacity as $$T_c = \frac{2}{3} \mu F_a \frac{r_2^2+r_2r_1+r_1^2}{r_2+r_1}$$

From what I have read this equation describes the torque capacity between a single clutch disc and the frictional material contacting it, usually however two clutch discs sandwich the frictional material so $T_c$ is then actually multipled by 2.

I am wondering if I can apply this same concept to a set of plates with varying material (therefore different $\mu$) being clapped together and represent it as a summation to understand the torque capacity of an assembly of metal plates. Is there any major pitfalls of using such an approximation?

Comment: look here https://nl.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/building-a-clutch-lock-up-model.html